# Part numbers on Johnson motors don't match their catalogures

Tags: motor, dc, hacking

I've bought three motors which look like cordless drill parts, DC. I intend to use motors 1 & 2 to drive the left and right sides of a robot, and the third will probably be useful for a future iteration. All I have at present is [this photo](http://i.ebayimg.com/t/3-x-Johnson-motors-DC-new-/00/s/MTYwMFgxMzY4/z/~AsAAOxylYZR5R9n/$%28KGrHqZHJCoFHKdg6n22BR5R9n%28Rs!~~60_58.JPG), ...

[image]

... but it clearly shows the following markings:

Motor 1 (black plastic gear)

```
70001
JOHNSON
3D2212
```

Motor 2 (same as motor 1)

```
70001
JOHNSON
3D3341
```

Motor 3 (slightly larger, metal gear, shaft does not extend beyond the gear)

```
1070033
JOHNSON
3E3731
```

**[Johnson Electric's part numbers](http://www.johnsonelectric.com/en/resources-for-engineers/motors/product-coding/dc-motors.html) have the format AA000AAA, which matches none of these markings. Are these older models, or am I using the wrong search terms?**

Comment: Your photo link doesn't work for me.

Comment: It's on eBay UK, also comes up with a google image search for the phrase `"3 x johnson motors"`. There are no markings beyond what I've listed and the Johnson logo, and there aren't many scale references.

Comment: The motors arrived in Friday so I'll report back once I've found some accurate tools to measure them with.

Comment: I measured the motors' physical dimensions and it seems they key part of the numbers is **700**. Googling 700 DC motor returned a number of RC-themed results, and a search for "Johnson 700" found that many Draper Expert power tools list "Johnson 700" as the motor type on the spec sheet.

Answer (score 2):

The Johnson HC683LP-022 is a 12 V (max), ~20000 RPM, 338 W motor with diameter 35.8 mm, intended for electric drills.

[image]

Johnson appear to make a very large variety of similar looking motors. Your best bet may be to search their site for the model that best matches the specification used in the advert of the ones you purchased and hope for the best.

Since the eBay listing has no information, you could measure and weigh them (without cog) when you receive them and compare with Johnson specs for various motors (they are sorted by casing diameter).

I'd then try them with lower voltages and monitor temperature.

There are disadvantages to buying from cheap eBay vendors.

Answer (score 1):

The bottom is probably a serial number.  If these came out of cordless drills, then the top number could be a marking from the drill manufacturer, rather than the motor manufacturer.  Often times when a company makes a motor directly for another manufacturer, they will put on the label whatever that manufacturer requests.  The other possibility is that because these are probably custom motors for the drill manufacturer, they use a custom model number that isn't on the website.  The model number on the website would only be for Johnson's standard product.  But as RedGrittyBrick pointed out, they may have a standard motor that is similar to these custom motors.